# Wordpress Custom Field and CSS Class

Tags: php, css, wordpress

```
<p class="myclass">
    <?php 
                        $portfolio_description = esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'portfolio_description', true));

                    ?></p>

                    <?php

                    if ($portfolio_description != '') {
                        echo "<p>$portfolio_description</p>";
                    } ?>
```

Hello everyone,

So I made up this custom field, to display a custom post description to my wordpress theme.

Everythin' works as expected, description is displayed, text is the same, no errors or anything.

BUT whenever i try to display the description into a paragraph, with a class, for somereason that paragraph class isn't displayed.

It only displays the raw description with no classes.

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Can I add a class into php script? And if so what modifications should I made?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wrapping/nesting is a bit off:

```
<p class="myclass">
    <?php 
        $portfolio_description = esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'portfolio_description', true));

        if ($portfolio_description != '') {
            echo $portfolio_description;
        } 
    ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Inspired by your answer, i changed my p class into a div, and set the font class into myclass p { my styles } Thank you!

Comment: Great! If this answer helped or solved your problem, please upvote/mark it as correct.